# Single Positional Indexer out of bounds Iterating through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing

I have a dataframe, myDF, one column of which I wish to set to zero using a combination of conditions from other columns and indexing with a second dataframe, criteriaDF.

myDF.head():

```
       DateTime  GrossPowerMW USDateTime_string  DateTime_timestamp  \
0  01/01/1998 00:00        17.804  01/01/1998 00:00 1998-01-01 00:00:00   
1  01/01/1998 01:00        18.751  01/01/1998 01:00 1998-01-01 01:00:00   
2  01/01/1998 02:00        20.501  01/01/1998 02:00 1998-01-01 02:00:00   
3  01/01/1998 03:00        22.222  01/01/1998 03:00 1998-01-01 03:00:00   
4  01/01/1998 04:00        24.437  01/01/1998 04:00 1998-01-01 04:00:00   

   Month  Day  Hour  GrossPowerMW_Shutdown  
0      1    3     0                 17.804  
1      1    3     1                 18.751  
2      1    3     2                 20.501  
3      1    3     3                 22.222  
4      1    3     4                 24.437
```

criteriaDF:

```
       STARTTIME  ENDTIME
Month                    
1            9.0     12.0
2            9.0     14.0
3            9.0     14.0
4            9.0     14.0
5            9.0     13.0
6            9.0     14.0
7            9.0     13.0
8            9.0     12.0
9            9.0     14.0
10           9.0     13.0
11           9.0     13.0
12           9.0     11.0
```

myDF is then run through the following for loop:

```
month = 1
for month in range (1, 13):
    shutdown_hours = range(int(criteriaDF.iloc[month]['STARTTIME']), int(criteriaDF.iloc[month]['ENDTIME']))
    myDF.loc[(myDF["Month"].isin([month])) & (myDF["Hour"].isin(shutdown_hours)) & (myDF["Day"].isin(shutdown_days)), "GrossPowerMW_Shutdown"] *= 0
    month = month + 1
```

This gives the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('myscript.py', wdir='C:myscript')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 87, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "myscript.py", line 111, in 
>       gross_yield, curtailed_yield, shutdown_loss, df_testing = calculate_loss(input_file, input_shutdownbymonth, shutdown_days)
>   #Returning df for testing/interrogation only. Delete once finished.
>
> File "myscript.py", line 79, in calculate_loss
>       shutdown_hours = range(int(criteriaDF.iloc[month]['STARTTIME']), int(criteriaDF.iloc[month]['ENDTIME']))
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1328, in __getitem__
>       return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1749, in _getitem_axis
>       self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1638, in _is_valid_integer
>       raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
>
> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

However the script works if I set

```
month = 0
for month in range (0, 12)
```

However this does not fit with my dataframe's indexing on the Column ['Month'] which runs 1 - 12 not 0 -> 11.

To confirm my understanding is  that

```
range (1, 13)
```

returns

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].
```

I have also tried manually running the code line by line with the code in the for loop with month = 12. So I am uncertain why using month in rage (1, 13) is not working, noting that 12 is the highest integer in the list range (1,13).

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) which is "Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position." So it just counts your rows from 0 to 11
you should use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which looks at the value of your index (so 1 to 12)